# Change Image in JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I've been working through the Oracle tutorial for images this one here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoadImageApp extends Component {

    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public LoadImageApp() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new LoadImageApp());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want to change the image that appears in the JFrame. If I say:

```
f.add(new LoadImageApp());      
f.revalidate();
f.repaint();
```

The new image will appear, behind the current one. What I'd like to do is remove the previous image and replace, but I can't work out how I'd go about doing this with this snippet of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use a JLabel to display the image? Then to change the image you just invoke the setIcon(...) method.

If you do need to do custom painting then:

1. For a Swing application you should extend JComponent, not Component
2. You should be overriding paintComponent(), not paint()
3. If you want to change the image then create a method like `setImage()` to change the image. Then  in that method you invoke repaint() to force the component to repaint itself. There is no need to create a new component and replace the component on the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, later on I'd like to use the 2D API to draw onto the picture, is this possible with a JLable the same as a JFrame?

Comment: Custom painting is done by override the paintComponent() method of a component. So, yes, you can do custom painting of top of the JLabel. Using a JLabel gives you the benefit of having the preferred size automatically calcuated based on the size of the image. If you create a custom component to draw the image and do other painting, then you are responsible for implementing the getPreferredSize() method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you are stacking up images without removing the old ones.
Do the following instead:
In the original code:

```
BufferedImage img = new LoadImageApp();
f.add(img);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

When you want to load another image:

```
img = new LoadImageApp();
// No need to add the image to the frame again, just refresh
f.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here my contribution, with a main for testing. The idea is changing the base JPanel where de image is charged. This class could be added in another JPanel or JFrame and still you will have the access to change the image.

```
public class ImageButton extends JPanel {


    public  JLabel imageLabel;

    public ImageButton() {
        super();
        iniGUI();
    }


    private void iniGUI() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        imageLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton clickButton = new JButton("Select...");
        panel.add(clickButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        clickButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }



    public static void main(String...arg){

        JFrame cadre = new javax.swing.JFrame(" ");

        cadre.setContentPane(new  ImageButton());
        cadre.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        cadre.setLocation(300, 300);
        cadre.pack();
        cadre.setVisible(true);
        cadre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }



}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.